# Upgrade Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 without deleting Mac OS X

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, macosx

I used Universal USB Installer to push 14.04 LTS.  I booted into Linux from USB from EFI boot screen, and followed the prompts.  I got to the part that  asks,  "Installation type". Herein it states, "This computer currently has Mac OS X and Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS on it.  What would you like to do?" I am wondering if I choose:

"Erase disk and install Ubuntu"

...will it wipe out Mac OS X as well?

Other options include:

- Erase Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS and reinstall
- Encrypt the new Ubuntu installation for security
- Use LVM with the new Ubuntu Installation
- Something Else

Can someone kindly assist me with my inquiry?
Thanks.
-ricomon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the misunderstandable thing in "Erase disk"?

If it said "Erase partition", I'd share your doubt, but it clearly says it will erase the entire main hard disk.

"Erase Ubuntu and reinstall" may or may not wipe Mac OS X, depending on whether it is detected or not. The OS-Prober utility can not always be trusted, less so the interpretation of its output by Ubiquity (the installer)

I doubt the other options are what you want. From your title I take it that you want to upgrade the currently installed Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04. This is most easily done from inside the running Ubuntu 12.04. Simply boot the installed Ubuntu and follow these instructions:

- **Backup** your personal files
- Open a terminal
- Execute the following command:

  ```
  sudo do-release-upgrade
  ```

Now the upgrade process will begin. You may be asked a few question, most of which should be answerable by yes or no. Please make sure the PC keeps running and has a permanent internet connection and power supply, if possible. If the computer's battery runs empty or it disconnects from the internet during the upgrade, the OS may be rendered unusable (One of the many reasons to make a **backup** if your files). If this happens despite precautions, e.g. an outage at your ISP's, you may have to completely reinstall your Ubuntu system. The Mac OS X system will not be touched in the process.

Comment: Should I click on "Try Ubuntu without installing" and run the command sudo do-release-upgrade ? Or do I log into my 12.04 Ubuntu and then run sudo do-release-upgrade ? Also, what is the difference of clicking the "Install Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS" icon when I have clicked on "Try Ubuntu without installing" Thanks Seppi!

Comment: @ricomon Log in to your 12.04 and run the command. The do-release-upgrade upgrades the system the Installer replaces it.